# R Shiny output doesn't render in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny, reactive-programming

I am trying to use Bootstrap carousel in my R Shiny app. I want to put buttons, text outputs and plots (plotly) in each "slides".

At this point, carousel itself works great and the **FIRST** "slide" which has 2 plots inside **works**. But on the **second to the fourth** "slide", the text outputs and plots **do not render** and **buttons show up but don't work**, I can **only** see **UI components** such as panel boxes.

Before I move the plots and text outputs into the carousel, they works. So do they after I move them out from the carousel.

The following is my ui.R:

```
div(
id = "snapshot_carousel",
class="carousel slide",
`data-ride`="carousel",
`data-interval`="false",
tags$ol(
    class="carousel-indicators",
    tags$li(
        `data-target`="#snapshot_carousel",
        `data-slide-to`="0",
        "Slide 1",
        class="active"
    ),
    tags$li(
        `data-target`="#snapshot_carousel",
        `data-slide-to`="1",
        "Slide 2"
    ),
    tags$li(
        `data-target`="#snapshot_carousel",
        `data-slide-to`="2",
        "Slide 3"
    ),
    tags$li(
        `data-target`="#snapshot_carousel",
        `data-slide-to`="3",
        "Slide 4"
    )
),
div(
    class="carousel-inner",
    div(
        class="item active",
        div(
            class="well well-lg",
            div(
                class="panel-body",
                column(
                    width = 3, 
                    wellPanel(
                        class = 'panels',
                        id = 'actv_loan_well',
                        h4("Active Accounts"),
                        hr(),
                        tags$div(textOutput("t1"), class = "med_number")
                    )
                ),
                column(
                    width = 9, 
                    wellPanel(
                        class = 'panels',
                        column(
                            width = 3, 
                            h4("Active Balance"),
                            hr(),
                            tags$div(textOutput("t1"), class = "med_number")
                        ),
                        column(
                            width = 9,
                            plotlyOutput("actv_bal_hist", height = "100px")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    div(
        class="item",
        div(
            class="well well-lg",
            div(
                class="panel-body",
                fluidRow(
                    column(
                        width = 6,
                        wellPanel(
                            class = 'panels',
                            h4("Account Closed"),
                            hr(),
                            fluidRow(
                                column(width = 9,
                                       tags$div(textOutput("n_acct"), class = "big_number")),
                                column(width = 3,
                                       actionButton("acct_closed", "", icon = icon('plus-circle', 'fa-fw'))
                                )
                            )  
                        )  
                    ),
                    column(
                        width = 6,
                        wellPanel(
                            class = 'panels',
                            h4("Balance Closed"),
                            hr(),
                            tags$div(textOutput("bal_close"), class = "big_number"),
                            plotlyOutput("bal_close_plot", height = "250px")    
                        )   
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    div(
        class="item",
        div(
            class="well well-lg",
            div(
                class="panel-body"
            )
        )
    ),
    div(
        class="item",
        div(
            class="well well-lg",
            div(
                class="panel-body"
            )
        )
    )
)#,
# a(
#     class="left carousel-control",
#     href="#snapshot_carousel",
#     `data-slide`="prev",
#     span(
#         class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"
#     ),
#     span(
#         class="sr-only",
#         "Previous"
#     )
# ),
# a(
#     class="right carousel-control",
#     href="#snapshot_carousel",
#     `data-slide`="next",
#     span(
#         class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"
#     ),
#     span(
#         class="sr-only",
#         "next"
#     )
# )
```

)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution using CSS. It may not be the best solution but hopefully it can help people with similar needs.

The solution is to add carousel classes to the tabset panel. Note that I used to have # href = "#tabs-1" in each li(a()) for switch tabs, which has conflict with the sliding effect. It works after I take

```
div(
id = "my_carousel",
class="carousel slide",
`data-ride`="carousel",
`data-interval`="false",
tags$ul(
    id = "stab",
    class = "nav nav-pills nav-justified shiny-tab-input",
    tags$li(
        class = "active",
        `data-target`="#my_carousel",
        `data-slide-to`="0",
        a(
            `data-toggle`="tab",
            "Slide 1"
        )
    ),
    tags$li(
        `data-target`="#my_carousel",
        `data-slide-to`="1",
        a(
            `data-toggle`="tab",
            "slide 2"
        )
    ),
    tags$li(
        `data-target`="#my_carousel",
        `data-slide-to`="2",
        a(
            `data-toggle`="tab",
            "slide 3"
        ) 
    )
),
div(
    class="tab-content carousel-inner",
    role="listbox",
    div(
        class="item tab-pane active",
        div(
            class="well well-lg",
            div(
                class="panel-body"
            )
        )
    ),
    div(
        class="item tab-pane",
        div(
            class="well well-lg",
            div(
                class="panel-body"
            )
        )
    ),
    div(
        class="item tab-pane",
        div(
            class="well well-lg",
            div(
                class="panel-body"
            )
        )
    )
)
)
```